# Add a string to column names ending with digits R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

My data looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(Date = c("2020-10-01", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-03", "2020-10-04", "2020-10-05"),
             Department = c("blue", "green", "yellow" ,"red", "purple"),
             Covid_10 = rnorm(5),
             Covid_12 = rnorm(5)
             )
```

I want to create a function that adds the string **"_peak"** to the end of the column names which  contain 2 digits at the end. For example, in my dataset I have two columns which have 2 digits at the end of their names (Covid_10 and Covid_12).

I would like the column names to look like this **"Covid_10_peak"**. So the string "_peak" gets pasted to the end of the column name. I would like this only for column names with 2 digits at the end.

The other column names that do not have digits (Date, Department) at the end should be untouched.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rename_with` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_with(~paste0(., '_peak'), matches('\\d{2}$'))

#  Date       Department Covid_10_peak Covid_12_peak
#  <chr>      <chr>              <dbl>         <dbl>
#1 2020-10-01 blue              1.93          2.26  
#2 2020-10-02 green            -1.08          0.985 
#3 2020-10-03 yellow            0.0394        1.22  
#4 2020-10-04 red              -1.81         -0.303 
#5 2020-10-05 purple            0.605         0.0165
```

Or in base R -

```
cols <- grep('\\d{2}$', names(df))
names(df)[cols] <- paste0(names(df)[cols], '_peak')
df
```